# To what extent is the Pentagon able to influence or pressure POTUS?

Tags: united-states, president, military

Some countries are routinely criticized for their military having considerable influence over politics and foreign policy. E.g. Pakistan.

How does the situation in the USA compare to those countries?

What is the scale of the Pentagon's ability to influence/override/pressurize POTUS?

For instance, as far as I know, Pentagon opposed the decision of Barack Obama and Trump of withdrawing troops from Afghanistan. I also heard that they are still opposing Biden's decision regarding the withdrawal of troops. So, why could they stop Barack Obama from calling troops back, while they could not stop Biden?

I also think that Pentagon has great influence regarding the defense budget/procurement and the military exports.

Can anyone clarify this matter to me?

Comment: Are you talking about specific, legal influence, or more fuzzy influence through advocacy and politics? If it's the latter, I think there's no objective answer since that's going to involve the personalities of the individuals involved and the specific situation at the time. If you're interested **specifically** in the issue of the withdrawal from Afghanistan, then that's a specific question and would be answerable.

Answer (score 3):

I firmly believe that the US military will, ultimately, follow civilian control. **It isn't enough that the Pentagon is for or against a course of action, if they stand alone with their opinion. But usually they do not stand alone.** Tools at their disposal are:

- Confidential expert opinion.
  If the generals say "we can do this" or "we cannot do that," the civilian leadership of the Pentagon and the White House would be hard-pressed to say "you're wrong." They might find overriding *political* reasons to come to a different decision, however.
- Related: Making (or not making) plans.
  The military has many different contingency plans. The political leadership might direct the military to "provide military options," but it cannot come up with detailed courses of action. So in a sudden crisis, the President usually has to decide between one the existing contingency plans, doing nothing, and waiting for a new plan to be written.
- Public expert opinion.
  Serving military officers are limited in what they can say in public, short of the splash of a public resignation. But there are ways to get their opinion out, and it may be politically damaging for the President to openly go against expert advice and not to *stand with the troops.*
- Lobbying Congress.
  The US has a balance of power (*checks and balances*) between the executive and the legislative. Congress legislates things which might, in other countries, be the legitimate decision of the government, the defense bureaucracy and military staffs. Being *questioned* by Congress is a way for serving officers to make statements on politically relevant questions -- they have to answer to the best of their ability, after all.

If you want a nice example of military influence over the civilian government, look at the [Marine Corps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_Marine_Corps) existence and the assignment of roles. Few other countries give such an autonomy *within* the military structure to their landing forces -- their own air force, for instance. Why?

- The USMC has a very good public image, based on heroic actions in the past.
- They defined a role as middleweight, immediate readiness forces. It used to be that they were simply the immediate readiness forces, when the Army needed months to prepare for action. But now special operations forces are even faster, and the Stryker brigade combat teams are also middleweight.
- The USMC is very effective at lobbying congress, however. Read about the [Douglas Mansfield Act](https://www.usni.org/magazines/naval-history-magazine/2019/june/propaganda-machine-stalins) ...

Another example would be independence struggle of the Army Air Force to become the Air Force and the [Key West Agreement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_West_Agreement).

Both are examples where the US military participated in a public policy debate, and shaped it through lobbying work, but ultimately the decisions were made by the political leadership.